# Where to include 'while loop' to ask for user input several times? Python

Tags: python, json, api, loops

I'm working on a simple app that will search activities for users. I came across two problems. I tried to include 'while loop' to search for new activity if user is not satisfied.

example JSON

```
{
    "activity":"LearnGraphQL",
    "type":"education",
    "participants":1,
    "price":0,
    "link":"https://graphql.org/",
    "key":"2167064",
    "accessibility":0.8
}
```

Can you recommend how to solve this?

Another thing that is not working is in this part:

```
for item in activity_possibilities :
    if question2 == 'y':
      a = Activity(activity_list, activity_possibilities["participants"] > 1)
```

how to make second argument to return actvities that in 'participants' key have value higher than 1?

```
import requests
import json


class Activity :

    def __init__(self, activity, participants) :
        self.activity_activity = activity
        self.activity_participants = participants


activity_type = ("education", "recreational", "social", "diy",
             "charity", "cooking", "relaxation", "music", "busywork")


url = "http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?type="


question1 = input(f"Select one of the folowing: {activity_type}")
question2 = input(f"\nDo you have company? y/n")


response = requests.get(url + question1)  
activity_possibilities = response.json()


activity_list = activity_possibilities["activity"]

activity_objects = []


for item in activity_possibilities :
    if question2 == 'y':
        a = Activity(activity_list, activity_possibilities["participants"] > 1)
    else:
        a = Activity(activity_list, activity_possibilities["participants"] == 1)
    activity_objects.append(a)



print(f"\nMaybe you can try {a.activity_activity}")

last_question = input("\nDo you like this activity? y/n")
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's critical in understanding Python code.

Comment: The second argument to `Activity()` is supposed to be a participants list. You're passing a boolean, the result of the `>` or `==` comparison.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see this mistake. Do you know what argument would return actvities that in 'participants' key have values higher than 1?

Comment: A list comprehension `[p for p in activity_possibilities['participants'] if p > 1]`

Comment: I still cannot get it to work ;/  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: What dictionary element contains the list of participants?

Comment: Update the question and show a sample value of `activity_possibilities` and explain what should be used as the `participatns` argument.

Comment: Why aren't you using `item` in the `for item in activity_possibilities` loop?

Comment: That's what I wrote at the beginning, but I got TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: If that's the value of `activity_possibilities`, you shouldn't be looping over it. It's not a list, it's just a single item.